# Parameters are not passing properly to downstream job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parameters, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to pass parameter values from upstream job to downstream job and only one parameter is passing exact value but not the other.

```
                    def newJob = build job: 'downstreamJob', propagate: false
                    parameters: [
                        [$class: 'ChoiceParameterValue', name: 'PARAM1', value: "${params.PARAM1}"],
                        [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameterValue', name: 'PARAM2', value: "${params.PARAM2}"]
                    ]
```

My upstream job has the same parameter name as downstream job which is `PARAM1` and `PARAM2`. But my downstream job is using different parameters such as `Active Choice Parameter` for `PARAM1` and `Active Choice Reference Parameter` for `PARAM2`. When I run the pipeline, PARAM1 is passing properly but for PARAM2 it is passing the fallback script. Is there any error in my definition of downstream job or is there any other way to define it?

I also tried with `string` for the parameter class, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create pipeline-syntax for my job and observed there is an issue in Jenkins fetching the `CascadeChoiceParameter` during the downstream job. So I modified my PARAM2 to Active choice and it's working now.